# Python - my else statement isn't working

Tags: python

I am creating a text based game and asked for the gender. But it seems as if my else statement is not working.

```
def genderask ():
gender = input ("Are you a he or a she?")
try:
    if gender == "he" or "she":
        print("Hello, ", name)
    else:
        print("Your answer was not he or she.")
        print
        genderask ()
except ValueError:
    print ("Your answer was not he or she.")
    print
    genderask
```

print
genderask ()

Comment: A great thing about Python is that the *expressions* used in an if or else statement can always be evaluated on their own.  At the Python interactive prompt try entering just: `gender = 'she'`; then `gender == 'he' or 'she'`.  Of for that matter, just see what the expression `'he' or 'she'` does by itself.

Comment: Note that under no circumstances will that code throw a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if gender == "he" or gender == "she":

Comment: Thank you so much Pavel Chernikov